# Can't update an object's property in my database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework with the Northwind example database.

I have this object:

```
Product p = new Product { ProductName = "New awesome Product" };
Category c = new Category { CategoryName = "Cool Category" };
p.Category = c;
pdm.Insert(p);
```

pdm being a class that handles CRUD actions. The pdm class uses this working code:

```
using (var ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            ctx.Products.Add(p);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

However, if I want to update the category to a completely new category, I try this:

```
p.Category = new Category { CategoryName = "Even Cooler Category" };
p.ProductName = "Now even more awesome";
pdm.Update(p);
```

Which calls this code in the pdm class:

```
 using (var ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            Product p = ctx.Products.Find(updatedProduct.ProductID);
            ctx.Entry(p).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedProduct);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

My problem: the name of my product is changed in the database, the Category remains the same. Why is the Category not changing in my database? The category ID of my product row stays the same, and neither is a new category being made in my database. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category is a child of the Product Entity. SetValues only sets simple types and will not set related objects. You will have to handle setting the Category manually yourself, or use a library like Automapper to do this for you.